# Did steamboats on the Mississippi have individual cabins?

Tags: antebelllum, steamboat

If you were an upper deck passenger, could you have a cabin all to yourself, or would you have to have a roommate?

Comment: I have often wondered about the general quality of even the most luxurious accommodations on sea or land; I suspect by modern-day standards, luxury hotels and ship cabins would be shocking until well into the 20th century. I believe private baths were a rarity in US hotels, even in Manhattan in the early 1900s and before that they may have been non-existent. There was both custom and lack of technology that made luxuries of today hard to duplicate. Aboard ships, I am guessing hot running water might not have been present in the 19th century.

Answer (score 2):

Private rooms were not unheard of. According to a widely quoted news article from the *Niles’ Weekly Register*, the *Washington*, built in 1815-1816, had "[three handsome private rooms](http://steamboattimes.com/steamboats_1811~61_p1.html)".